# How to calculate standard deviation in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate standard deviation of 40 data points, through `R`. I was not able to do that...

I have tried:

```
> sd{1, 2, 3}
Error: unexpected '{' in "sd{"
> sd(1, 2, 3)
Error in sd(1, 2, 3) : unused argument (3)
```

and also tried:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3)
> sd(x)
[1] 1
```

It gives the output '1' but I believed that the standard deviation of 1, 2 and 3 and not 1.

What am I doing wrong here? Forgive me, I am a beginner

Comment: What do you believe it to be? I believe it to be 1, as does R and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard+deviation+%281%2C+2%2C+3%29).

Comment: Well, sigma(n-1) is 1 for [1, 2, 3]; so R is correct

Comment: x <- c(1,2,3,4); sd(x) will return 1.29... as it should be

Comment: It shows no understanding of the question being asked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `c` inside `sd`:

```
sd(c(1, 2, 3))
# [1] 1
```

It returns `1`. This is the ***sample*** standard deviation, an estimator of the standard deviation of the population, based on a denominator of `n - 1`. This is the default behavior of Rs `sd` function.

If you want to calculate the standard deviation of the ***population*** (denominator `n`), you can use:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)

sqrt(mean(x ^ 2) - mean(x)^2)
# [1] 0.8164966
```

If you know both the sample standard deviation and the length of the vector (i.e., the number of elements), you can use this approach to calculate the population standard deviation:

```
n <- length(x)  # number of values
std <- sd(x)    # sample standard deviation

sqrt((std ^ 2) * ((n - 1) / n))
# [1] 0.8164966
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem. I will tick it in the next 6 mins